# How could I remove the last character from a letter array in c?

Tags: arrays, c

I was given a project where the user has to insert characters with some restrictions, but that is not the problem.

The problem is when the user presses "BACKSPACE" it should delete the last character stored in the array, but in my case it doesn't delete, it comes back so the user can replace it and that's not the goal here.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

main(){
int size = 0;
   int pos = 0;
   int var;

      printf("Enter how many letters you want to write:");
      scanf("%d", &size);

    char text[size];

    printf("Enter the characters:\n");


do{
    var = getche();
    if((var >= 65) && (var <= 90) || (var >= 192) && (var <= 221) || (var == 32)){

        text[pos] = (char) var;
        text[pos+1] = 0;
        pos++;
    }

    else if (var == 8){
        if (pos > 0){
        text[pos] = 0;
        text[pos] += " ";
        pos--;
        }
     else{printf("Error");}
    }
    else{
         text[pos] = 0;
         system("cls");
         printf("Enter the characters: \n");
         printf("%s", text);
    }

}while (pos< size);
    printf("\n\nFinal string : ");

    printf("%s", text);
}
```

All the help is much apreciated.

Comment: It might help if you provide an example of expected behavior vs. observed.

Comment: post a complete example, please.

Comment: this is all my code

Comment: Also the line `text[pos] += " ";` should be changed to `text[pos] += ' ' `;

Comment: It seems to me you have things in the wrong order. `--pos; text[pos] = 0;`. This doesn't do what you expect, and you should be getting a warning for it. `text[pos] += " ";` If you want to add a space character use `' '` but I'm not sure why you'd want to there since you're trying to erase something.

Comment: @AnaCachoPaulos This is not all of your code. A complete example has your includes and at least a main function that compiles and runs.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste your complete code. The part currently shown in the question cannot be compiled.

Comment: yeah I already tried text[pos] += ' '  but it didnt work so I tried this way

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes I am trying to erase the last character, this space "trick" was a tip from a friend but it didn't work or I'm using it wrong

Comment: I'm gonna guess those numbers are the ascii values for letters, but you may want to replace that with character literals.

Comment: @EmanuelP in the task I was given I have to use ascii values :/

Comment: What you have posted yields a lot of warnings. Some of them are certain bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear the output and print again the new text when you the *getche* gets a backspace.
The code below performs what you are asking for, further improvement can be done, I'll leave that to you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
int size = 0;
   int pos = 0;
   int var;

      printf("Enter how many letters you want to write:");
      scanf("%d", &size);

    char text[size];

    printf("Enter the characters:\n");


do{
    var = getche();
    if((var >= 65) && (var <= 90) || (var >= 192) && (var <= 221) || (var == 32)){

        text[pos] = (char) var;
        text[pos+1] = 0;
        pos++;
    }
    else if (var == 8){
        if (pos > 0){
        pos--;
        text[pos] = 0;
        system("cls");
        printf("Enter the characters: \n");
        printf("%s", text);
        }
     else{printf("Error");}
    }
    else{
         text[pos] = 0;
         system("cls");
         printf("Enter the characters: \n");
         printf("%s", text);
    }
}while (pos< size);

    printf("\n\nFinal string : ");

    printf("%s", text);
}
```